# Java HiLo Game - Can't Generate New Guesses

Tags: java

SORRY I know there are other posts on this game, but my question is specific. I just started learning Java and threw together this HiLo game, but I am struggling to get 2 things down -

1) If a user wants to play again, how do I get it to generate a new pick? Right now if you play again, you get the same pick
2) If a user chooses to abort the game, I am not getting the message to generate

Help me pretty please, I'm new and vulnerable to Java!

```
package lab4;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class hilo 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //randomly pick a number between 1-100
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pick = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        int count = 0;
        boolean play = true;

        //prompt user to guess      
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("*---------------------------------*");
        System.out.println("* Guess a number between 1-100:   *");
        System.out.println("* (enter \"0\" to end at any time)  *");
        System.out.println("*---------------------------------*");
        int guess = scan.nextInt();

        //on each guess, say if too low or too high
        while (play = true)
        {   
            while (guess != pick && guess !=0)
            {

                if (guess < pick)
                {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Higher...");
                    System.out.println(pick);
                    guess = scan.nextInt();
                }

                else if (guess > pick)
                {  
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Lower...");
                    System.out.println(pick);
                    guess = scan.nextInt();
                }

            }


            if (guess == pick)
            {   
                System.out.println("You got it! It only took you " + count + " guesses.");
                System.out.println("Want to play again?");
                System.out.println("* Guess a number between 1-100:   *");
                System.out.println("* (enter \"0\" to end at any time)  *");
                guess = scan.nextInt();
                if (guess != 0)
                    play = true;
                else
                    play = false;
            }
        }

        if (play = false || guess == 0) 
        {
            System.out.println("Bummer. See you next time!");
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two little things,

```
int pick = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
// ...

//on each guess, say if too low or too high
while (play = true)
{
```

One `=` is assignment, two `==` is equality. So `while (play == true)` (which is verbose) *or* `while (play)`. And then move `pick` into the loop.

```
// int pick = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
// ...
while (play) {   
    int pick = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

And that should fix both problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a new value for `pick` variable in your if condition where you test the equality of `guess` and `pick`

```
if (guess == pick)
{   
  System.out.println("You got it! It only took you " + count + " guesses.");
  System.out.println("Want to play again?");
  System.out.println("* Guess a number between 1-100:   *");
  System.out.println("* (enter \"0\" to end at any time)  *");
  guess = scan.nextInt();

  pick = rand.nextInt(100) + 1; // new value

  if (guess != 0)
    play = true;
  else
    play = false;
}
```